# How to get the hover function to work on bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys i am using bootstrap and have a div with some text in it. However for some reason the basic hover functions do not work when i try it.

HTml:

```
  <div class = "Text">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <h1>text1</h1>
      <h2>text2</h2>
      <h3>text3</h3><br/>
    <p>Time to make this move to the side</p>
  </a>  
 </div>
```

All these are sepreate and been moved near each other. I can make each one a link however i want to make it so when u hover around their area they all change from colour white to red.

I tried multiple things but the best one i have got is :

```
.Text h1:hover {
    color: green;
    height: 700px;
}
```

Also tried this :

```
.Text *: hover {
    color: green;
}
```

Any help would be great

Edit:

Ye sorry i dont think i made the question clear, i want to change all the colors , for h1 h2 and h3 and p tag not just h1 when you hover over any element

So far the closest i have got is

```
.text h1:hover, h2:hover, h3:hover, p:hover {
    color: green;
}
```

But that does it individually and not all together.

Comment: Remove the space between h1 and :hover. Thus: Text h1:hover {

Comment: Ah yes but that did nothing , just changes 1 element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix has to do with your `.navbar-brand`, add the following to it:

```
.navbar-brand:hover * {
    color: green;
}
```

Which results in the below snippet:

```css
.Logo{
 margin-top: 21px;
}

.Logo h1 {
    font-family: lokicola-font;
    font-size: 69px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
 width: 90px;
 float: left; 
 color: #FFF;
}

.Logo h2 {
    font-family: lokicola-font;
    font-size: 79px;
    margin-top: -26px;
    margin-left: 5px;
 width: 90px;
 float: left; 
 color: #FFF;
}

.Logo h3 {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 49px;
    margin-top: -14px;
    margin-left: 28px;
 width: 90px;
 float: left; 
 color: #FFF;
}

.Logo p {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-top: -26px;
    margin-left: 15%;
 width: 330px;
 float: left; 
 color: #FFF;
}

.Logo :hover {
 color: green;
}

.navbar-brand:hover * {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">  
  <div class="container">     
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class = "Logo">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <h1>1oca</h1>
          <h2>Cola</h2>
          <h3>Journey</h3><br/>
        <p>Refreshing the world, one story at a time</p>
      </a>  
     </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">  
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Drinks<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
                <li><a href="#">Coca Cola</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Sprite</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Dr Pepper</a></li>   
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer

```
.navbar-brand:hover h1, 
.navbar-brand:hover h2, 
.navbar-brand:hover h3, 
.navbar-brand:hover p {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Meaning: `.navbar-brand:hover * { color: green}`

Comment: ye :) dunno how it took me so long

Comment: its a shame you answered your own question because I found the same answer you did, except with the global selector `*`, but in a way it's also a good thing you did so win win

Answer (score 0):

Your probleme is in the css you have space between h1 and :hover

```css
.text *:hover {
    color: green;
    height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <h1>text1</h1>
    <h2>text2</h2>
    <h3>text3</h3><br/>
    <p>Time to make this move to the side</p>
  </a>  
</div>
```

Comment: Ye sorry i dont think i made the question clear, i want to change all the colours , for h1 h2 and h3 and p tag not just h1

Comment: Ah tried that is well and did not work, again if i hover h1 tag only that turns green, then if i hover over h2 tag only that turns green etc

Comment: Fixed with * operator try it now

Comment: Ah tried that is well and did not work, again if i hover h1 tag only that turns green, then if i hover over h2 tag only that turns green etc

Comment: ah you want only the hoverd element ? to be green !

Comment: No :0 For example i have text which i have placed in like a diagonal line. When one of the elements gets hoverd over , they all change color.

Comment: you mean if I hover h1, then h2 h3 and p would be change color , and if h2 then h1 h3 p would change and son on...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/us6ho84a/1/ That is the link to all my code, obv it does not look like this but can you see when i have my other code there it does this? 1 by 1 etc

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this in Dreamweaver and I believe it is what you want.

```css
.text h1:hover, h2:hover, h3:hover, p:hover {
    color: green;
    height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <h1>text1</h1>
      <h2>text2</h2>
      <h3>text3</h3><br/>
    <p>Time to make this move to the side</p>
  </a>  
 </div>
```

Comment: Ye sorry i dont think i made the question clear, i want to change all the colours , for h1 h2 and h3 and p tag not just h1

Comment: I fixed my answer to your response.

Comment: Ah again does the same thing, if i hover h1 tag only that turns green, if i hover h2 tag, that turns green etc etc

Comment: so you want them to all turn green at the same time?

Comment: ye :)  that is the plan hopefully

Comment: try `.text :hover {
 color: green;
}`

Comment: Nope :( still just single not all together

Comment: are you sure? So when you use [This Link](https://jsfiddle.net/us6ho84a/) and hover over text1 you dont see the rest turn green?

Comment: Ye that works for me , and that is what i want but for some reason in my text it does not

Comment: jsfiddle.net/us6ho84a/1 That is the link to all my code, obv it does not look like this but can you see when i have my other code there it does this? 1 by 1 etc

Comment: Even though you solved it ,  I figured since I put this thing together might as well post it. It is just another method. @AGE looks like the most simple method for the situation so I recommend that. I just rebuild it [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/s02jvw5e/)